# Can somebody help me fix my router's page from not showing all of its components?

Tags: networking, ip-address, router, gateway

I went to my default gateway to check some things out and I noticed that the layout of the page changed and now is looking a little bit ugly and it's hard for me to navigate in it. Can somebody help me??

[Picture of my router's page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDANh.png)

[How It should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Q0I.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your login-page does not load its style sheet.

1. Your Browser has something configured that prevents it -> Try a different browser
2. You disabled it on your gateway -> Look for a setting on the gateway
3. Further Troubleshooting can be made if you look at the page via an Inspector (can be enabled in most browsers under developer options)
4. If nothing helped so far try resetting your gateway (as long as you are aware of the consequences and are allowed to do so).